# Android find value in arraylist<arraylist>string

Tags: android, arraylist, indexing

I have an arraylist of arraylist of String as given below:

```
[
 [37, 0, nirmal, kumar, SCC            , nikk3008@outlook.com, 12], 
 [38, 0, nirmal, kumar, MyChurchMateApp, nikk3008@outlook.com, 12]
]
```

`clientChurchList` is my arraylist of arraylist of `string`.

I am using the following code to search a particular value in this list:

```
      private boolean checkForClientID() {
          if (clientChurchList.contains(Integer.parseInt(clientid)))
          {
            Log.e("ClientId is Found", clientid);
             return true;
          }
         else{
              Log.e("ClientId is Not Found", clientid);
        }
         return false;
      }
```

where `clientId` is first index value in the list but it always printing in log

```
  ClientId is Not Found(25936): 37
```

but you can see that it contain the value 37 , whay may I have done wrong?

Comment: a/ clientChurchList contains lists, not ints. b/ each sublist contains Strings, by your own admission, not ints.

Comment: it means i have to find the value in loop.

Answer (score 0):

`clientChurchList.contains(Integer.parseInt(clientid))` means you are trying to find an object of type `Integer` inside `clientChurchList`, which contains objects of another type. But your gold is to find `String` inside `ArrayList` inside `ArrayList`. You can avoid this mistake during compilation by using generic version of `ArrayList`

Comment: it means i have to do clientChurchList.contains(clientid) something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to loop the first `ArrayList` since asking directly `contains` on the parent `ArrayList`, will loop the objects it contains which are in fact of the type `ArrayList` and not `String`

```
for(ArrayList<String> array : clientChurchList){
    if (array.contains(clientid)){
        Log.e("ClientId is Found", clientid);
        return true;
    }
}
return false
```

Comment: nota : there are very little chances that an `ArrayList<String>` can contain an int. Also I would insist that `ArrayList<String, String>` is not a valid declaration.

Comment: @njzk2 Agreed, updated the code, didn't read his code good enough